# Dropdown selection is not changing on .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue where the value of a dropdown element is being changed correctly, but what is being displayed on the page as the selected value is not correct.

For example, based on the logic below, when the value 'SEL' is selected for #searchParam1, then #searchParam2's value should be reset to 'SEL' through the resetSelection() method.  And indeed, when I debug I can verify that the value is being changed as expected.  However, the dropdown visually remains the same, even with the .change() call.

I've done my best to parse down the code to what pertains exactly to my question, so please excuse any typos or missing brackets (the full code does not produce any errors at any point).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $('#searchParam1').change(function () {
         var value = $('#searchParam1').val()
         var number = 1
         if (value == 'SEL') {
             resetSelection(number)
         }
     })
     $('#searchParam2').change(function () {
         var value = $('#searchParam2').val()
         var number = 2
         if (value == 'SEL') {
             resetSelection(number)
         }
     })
 })

function resetSelection(number) {
     $('#searchParam' + (number + 1).toString()).val('SEL').change()
 }
```

Comment: try to add last function resetSelection(number) {
     $('#searchParam' + (number + 1).toString()).val('SEL').change().attr('selected')
 }

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. The problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work just fine: fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/daniel0mullins/u1emgphy/)

HTML

```
<select id="searchParam1">
  <option>SEL</option>
  <option>Other1</option>
  <option>Other2</option>
</select>

<select id="searchParam2">
  <option>SEL</option>
  <option>Other1</option>
  <option>Other2</option>
</select>
```

JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#searchParam1').change(function() {
     var value = $('#searchParam1').val()
     var number = 1
     if (value == 'SEL') {
       resetSelection(number)
     }
   });

   $('#searchParam2').change(function() {
     var value = $('#searchParam2').val()
     var number = 2
     if (value == 'SEL') {
       resetSelection(number)
     }
   });
});

function resetSelection(number) {
  $('#searchParam' + (number + 1).toString()).val('SEL');
}
```